# 80s/90s TV show with hero with abilities similar to Unbreakable?

Tags: identify-this-tv-show, science-fiction, action

When the movie *Unbreakable* came out, it triggered so many memories of a show I saw as a kid in the 80s/early 90s, but I can't remember the name of the show.

The TV show was similar to *The Six Million Dollar Man*, but instead of being bionic, the main character gained his abilities from some sort of mysterious chemical spill. The hero had a son, and in later episodes in the show, the son also experienced a similar chemical spill and gained the same abilities.

The main ability was the hero's ability to heal. He survives a train crash without any injury, instantaneously heals from cuts on his hands from broken glass, etc. One of the major plot points is avoiding discovery, so hospitals, doctors, and government agents (possibly rogue ones) are frequent antagonists. I think he was also a scientist, and possibly a spy. He may have had other enhanced physical abilities, like strength and speed.

The hero works with a small group of people who know his secret, and performs missions to help people, like many of the other spy/secret agent shows of its time (*The Six Million Dollar Man*, *Knight Rider*, *A-Team*, *Greatest American Hero*, etc.)

Does anybody have any ideas what this show was called? It's been on my mind since *Unbreakable* came out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is "I-Man" with Scott Bakula. He gets regeneration from a chemical spill and works for the government. His son also gets the same powers.  Both need light as the regeneration stops in total darkness.

Comment: Man!  Scott Bakula could do everything.

Comment: Yes! That's exactly the movie I was thinking of! I didn't remember the details very well, but you nailed it! Thanks! Unfortunately, I can't seem to be able to buy/rent this anywhere. :(